# Eloquent query to group users (total users, Admins users, Control operators, guards)

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I have a query where I `count all users`, `total users with role "admin"`, `total users with role "control_operator"` and `total users with role "guard"`.

The query is working but there is a small glitch/bug I can't figure out.

There are actually 2 users in the database, one with `super_admin & admin` roles and the other with `control_operator`. The front-end is showing this:

[image]

Why is it counting 3 users when there are only 2?

This is my query

```
// Retrieve the counts of admins, users, control operators, and security guards
        $countData = User::selectRaw('
        SUM(CASE WHEN roles.name = "admin" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as totalAdmins,
        COUNT(*) as totalUsers,
        SUM(CASE WHEN roles.name = "control_operator" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as totalControl,
        SUM(CASE WHEN roles.name = "security_guard" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as totalGuards
    ')->join('model_has_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id')
      ->join('roles', 'model_has_roles.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
      ->first();
```

Comment: Perhaps there is some other `role.name` not covered by the `CASE`s ?

Comment: There are other roles, but I don't need to query them

Comment: Ok, but the `COUNT` is a total of _all_ users, right? I do not see any filter(s) to reduce to only the 3 roles being totaled. Perhaps the total should be sum of the 3 `CASE` totals instead, or add a filter to the 3 roles being checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $countData = User::selectRaw('
    COUNT(DISTINCT users.id) as totalUsers,
    SUM(CASE WHEN roles.name = "admin" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as totalAdmins,
    SUM(CASE WHEN roles.name = "control_operator" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as totalControl,
    SUM(CASE WHEN roles.name = "security_guard" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as totalGuards
')
    ->join('model_has_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id')
    ->join('roles', 'model_has_roles.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
    ->first();
```